# Using Grep to search a list and return matches

Tags: linux, bash, grep, for, bioinformatics

I have a short list of 1000 gene names and a full list of 20000 gene names with ID numbers.

I have tried to set up a for loop to search for the shorter list in the full list to return the numbers.

This is the code:

```
#/bin/bash

LIST=$(cat ShortList.txt)

for i in ${LIST}
    do
    RESULT=$(grep -i ${i} FullList.txt)
    echo "${RESULT}" >> Final_List_With_Numbers
    done
```

The resulting file is empty- any advice on what to change?

Many thanks for the help!

Some troubleshooting I've already done:

- checked cat `Shortlist` works in command line
- checked cat `FullList` works in command line
- checked for loop works to just `echo "${i}"`
- checked `grep "gene" FullList` works in command line
- checked genes are in `FullList`

Comment: Do consider showing a representative sample of entries from both files.

Comment: Shortlist:
AP4B1
HSPB11
CIRBP-AS1
PRKRIP1
RAB4B
CCDC130
TREX1
TOR2A
IZUMO4
LY6G5C
CENPT
TARBP2
LCAT

FullList:
A1BG|1
A1CF|29974
A2BP1|54715
A2LD1|87769
A2ML1|144568
A2M|2
A4GALT|53947
A4GNT|51146
AAA1|404744
AAAS|8086

Comment: What does the FxF option in grep do? just trying to understand

Comment: @Cait don't add extra information in comments please. As you can see, they don't render clearly. Instead, [edit] your question and add anything you need there.

Answer (score 3):

First change is to not do this in a shell loop! That means you search the file once per gene name and will take much, much longer than necessary. Instead, use the `-f` option of `grep` to give it the list of names as input:

```
grep -iFxf ShortList.txt  FullList.txt > Final_List_With_Numbers
```

The options used are:

```
  -i, --ignore-case
          Ignore  case  distinctions in patterns and input data, 
          so that characters that differ only in case match each other.

   -F, --fixed-strings
          Interpret PATTERNS as fixed strings, not regular expressions.
   -f FILE, --file=FILE
          Obtain patterns from FILE, one per line.  If this option is 
          used multiple times or is combined with the -e (--regexp) option,
          search for all patterns given.  The empty file contains zero patterns, 
          and therefore matches nothing.
   -x, --line-regexp
          Select  only  those matches that exactly match the whole line.  
          For a regular expression pattern, this is like parenthesizing
          the pattern and then surrounding it with ^ and $.
```

The `-x` is particularly important since you don't want to find `LOC12345` when you search for `LOC1`. However, if your `FullList.txt` doesn't have *only* the gene name on each line, then you probably want to use `-w` instead of `-x`:

```
   -w, --word-regexp
          Select only those lines containing matches that form whole  words.   The  test  is  that  the
          matching  substring  must  either  be at the beginning of the line, or preceded by a non-word
          constituent character.  Similarly, it must be either at the end of the line or followed by  a
          non-word  constituent  character.   Word-constituent  characters are letters, digits, and the
          underscore.  This option has no effect if -x is also specified.
```

---

Now, the code you show should actually work. It would just be very, very slow and inefficient and likely return wrong results if one of the names in Shortlist can be a substring of one of the names in FullList. If you never got any results, I am guessing that your `ShortList.txt` was created in Windows and has Windows-style line endings (`\r\n`). That means that each `i` in your `for i in ${LIST}` loop won't be `geneName` but instead it will be `geneName\r` which doesn't exist in `FullList.txt` so no results are found.

If you test on a *nix file, it will work as expected:

```bsh
$ cat ShortList.txt 
name1
name2
name3

$ cat FullList.txt 
name3
name4
```

Now, run your exact code on those examples:

```
$ LIST=$(cat ShortList.txt); for i in ${LIST}; do 
   RESULT=$(grep -i ${i} FullList.txt);     
   echo "${RESULT}" >> Final_List_With_Numbers;
 done
$ cat Final_List_With_Numbers 



name3
```

Of course, it also contains empty lines since when you don't find a match, `$RESULT` is empty, but you are still `echo`ing it which means only an empty line will be printed. Yet another reason why using a shell loop here is a bad idea.

Comment: The definitely will want `-w` rather than `-x` I think since `FullList.txt` apparently contains *"names with ID numbers"* and the OP wants to *"return the numbers"*

Comment: This is all great thanks very much!